# How to change the z order of a chartjs polar chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want the numbers to be in front of the graph, but I didn't find an option for that:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution found was to setting the **z** property of the scale.ticks:

```
{
    type: "polarArea",
    options:{
        scale: {
            ticks: {
                z:3
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the solution? If yes please mark it as accepted answer so it can help someone else on the future.

Answer (score 0):

the answer above worked for me only after I defined an axis, r in this case as it was also an polar chart.

```
options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      r: {
        ticks: {
          z: 1
        }
      }
    }
  };
```